# Compiler error when using function composition: Cannot convert value of type `([Character]) -> String` to expected > argument type `_ -> _`

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, function-composition

I am playing around with the custom operator `>>>` for function composition that is suggested [here](https://www.objc.io/blog/2014/10/13/functional-snippet-2-function-composition/).

I have defined the following:

```
infix operator >>> { associativity left }
func >>> <A, B, C>(f: B -> C, g: A -> B) -> (A -> C) {
    return { x in f(g(x)) }
}

func toChars(s: String) -> [Character] {
    return s.characters.reduce([]) { (acc, c) in acc + [c] }
}

func myReverse(xs: [Character]) -> String {
    if let (head, tail) = xs.decompose {
        return String(myReverse(tail)) + String(head)
    }
    return ""
}
```

Now, when I want to put together those two functions like this:

```
func reverseString(s: String) -> String {
    return myReverse >>> toChars
}
```

I am getting the compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type `([Character]) -> String` to expected
>   argument type `_ -> _`.

According to my understanding this should work. `>>>` is defined to take two functions `f : B -> C` and `g : A -> B`. Looking at the structure of my usage, the following becomes clear:

- `g` in this case is `toChar : String -> [Character]`, so `A` is `String` and `B` is `[Character]`
- `f` in this case is `myReverse : [Character] -> String`, so `B` is `[Character]` and `C` is `String`

This matches the type definitions form above, however I am still getting a compiler error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is there a syntax issue with the code?

Note, I am using an `Array` extension where the function `decompose` is defined like so:

```
var decompose : (head: Element, tail: [Element])? {
    if count > 0 {
        return (self[0], Array(self[1..<count]))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myReverse >>> toChars` returns a *closure* of type `String -> String`,
you still have to call the closure with a string argument:

```
func reverseString(s: String) -> String {
    return (myReverse >>> toChars)(s)
}
```

But what you probably want is:

```
let reverseString = myReverse >>> toChars
```

In both cases, `reverseString` has the type `String -> String`,
so you can call it as

```
print(reverseString("foo"))
// oof
```